# Making a vector of specific length with random numbers

Tags: python-3.x

I tried writing a program that would give me the i,j and k components of a vector of a specified magnitude.

```
import random
import math

while True:
    a = random.uniform(0,1000)
    b = random.uniform(0,1000)
    c = random.uniform(0,1000)
    d = 69.420
    
    if math.sqrt(a**2 + b**2 + c**2) == d:
        print(a,b,c)
        break
```

But it seems that this program might take literally forever to give me an output.

What would faster or possible solution be?

#Update

```
import random
import math


while True:
    a2 = random.uniform(1,1000)
    b2 = random.uniform(1,1000)
    c2 = random.uniform(1,1000)
    d = 69.420

    d2 = a2 + b2 + c2
    
    a2 *= d/d2
    b2 *= d/d2
    c2 *= d/d2
    
    a = math.sqrt(a2)
    b = math.sqrt(b2)
    c = math.sqrt(c2)
    
    if math.sqrt(a**2 + b**2 + c**2) == d:
        print(a,b,c)
        break
```

As per suggested, but still taking a very long time to compute

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get three random numbers a2, b2, and c2. Those are your random squares. Add them up to get d2. You want the sum of the squares to be d squared, so multiply a2, b2, and c2 by d*d/d2. These are your new squares that add up to d squared. Now assign the square roots of a2, b2, and c2 to a, b, and c. Does that make sense?

Avoid dividing by zero. If d2 happens to be zero, just start over.

Comment: Refer to my post update to see if the steps I did are correct, because its still taking a while

Comment: Drop the whole loop. Just do it once. But instead of assigning a2, b2, and c2 to a, b, and c, assign their square roots, and print the answer.

Comment: a^2 + b^2 + c^2 add up to d, I want the root of the sum of their squares to add to do, not the sum of the squares.

Comment: Sorry, missed that. I’ve corrected it by just squaring d.

Comment: thanks for the help, can you point me towards the intuition or any source of what this method is called? because its very simple but creative at the same time. As in what technique would I apply to generalize this to different formulas where I want randomly generated outsputs with a non random input

Comment: To be honest it’s just algebra.

Comment: maybe I need to get some sleep lol. I was here thinking what is this black magic algo I am not aware of

Comment: The thinking was this: you want a random xyz vector of a given length. So you can just pick random values for  x,  y, and z, and then adjust the length. That’s all! One thing: the code will only pick non-negative values for the three components. If you want to allow negatives, you’ll need to change the arguments to the random function.